# Recommendation for learning Nach with Family

Tags: jewish-books, torah-study, tanach

I want to learn Nach on a "Pashat Pashut" format. I don't want to read the Hebrew-English Nach, neither the "fancy" Meforshim that delve through all of the Devrei Torah on each Passuk. Any suggestions for a resource that can help me?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.ou.org/oupress/product/nach-yomi-companion-volume-1/

Answer (score 1):

This is a great book that is easy to read with family. It gives a summary of every chapter in every book of nach...

https://seforimdeals.com/store15/index.php/all-books-seforim/yeshiva-seforim/nach/journey-through-nach-2-vol-set.html

Comment: Is it too deep?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to learn Nach on a "Pashat Pashut" format. I don't want to read the Hebrew-English Nach, neither the "fancy" Meforshim that delve through all of the Devrei Torah on each Passuk.

Sounds like the *M'tzudos* would be a perfect fit. This is a pair of commentaries written in the 1700s by R. David Altschuler. *M'tzudas Tziyon* explains difficult words and *M'tzudas David* provides a running commentary. (However, they're unavailable on *Rus*, *Echa*, and *Ester*.)

Alternatively, you can see what [929](http://www.929.org.il/pages/aboutEN.html) has to offer. But (1) it's in Hebrew; (2) it's (as of this writing) incomplete (it's publishing a chapter a day and is up to *Yish'aya* chapter 23); and (3) I don't know that it actually has what you're looking for.